# Trouble using two different databases in Mule JDBC flow

Tags: mysql, sql-server, jdbc, mule

I have two JDBC flows in Mule 3.2.0, one using MySQL database and other using SQLServer database.

```
<mule ...
    <spring:bean id="MySQL-jdbcDataSource"
        class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
        <spring:property name="driverName"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <spring:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://host:port/schema" />
    </spring:bean>

    <jdbc:connector name="MySQL-jdbcConnector"
        dataSource-ref="MySQL-jdbcDataSource" pollingFrequency="${MySQL.db.poll}"
        transactionPerMessage="false">
        <jdbc:query key="read" value="${MySQL.db.jdbc_query}" />
    </jdbc:connector>

    <flow name="MySQL-flow">

        <jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="read"
            connector-ref="MySQL-jdbcConnector">
            <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
            <property key="receiveMessageInTransaction" value="true"/>
        </jdbc:inbound-endpoint>

        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="path" connector-ref="first-level">
            <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                <add-message-property key="identifier" value="MySQL"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>
            <vm:transaction action="NONE"/>
        </vm:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

And

```
<mule ... 
    <spring:bean id="SQLServer-jdbcDataSource"
        class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
        <spring:property name="driverName"
            value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <spring:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=schema" />
    </spring:bean>

    <jdbc:connector name="SQLServer-jdbcConnector"
        dataSource-ref="SQLServer-jdbcDataSource" pollingFrequency="${SQLServer.db.poll}"
    transactionPerMessage="false">
        <jdbc:query key="read" value="${SQLServer.db.jdbc_query}" />
    </jdbc:connector>

    <flow name="SQLServer-flow">
        <jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="read"
        connector-ref="SQLServer-jdbcConnector">
            <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
            <property key="receiveMessageInTransaction" value="true"/>
        </jdbc:inbound-endpoint>

       <vm:outbound-endpoint path="${sv.vm.queue.name}" connector-ref="first-level-xform">
           <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                <add-message-property key="${sv.vm.msg.identifier}" value="SQLServer"/>
           </message-properties-transformer>
           <vm:transaction action="NONE"/>
       </vm:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

When I deploy any one of these floes in mule-deploy.properties, it runs ok. But when I deploy both of these flows at the same time, none of them works. I do not get any error or exception, but it seems like none of these flows run.

Any ideas what might be wrong? Probably something related to JDBC transactions?

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2 different flows in same application .. then remove :-

```
<spring:bean id="SQLServer-jdbcDataSource"
        class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
        <spring:property name="driverName"
            value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <spring:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=schema" />
    </spring:bean>

    <jdbc:connector name="SQLServer-jdbcConnector"
        dataSource-ref="SQLServer-jdbcDataSource" pollingFrequency="${SQLServer.db.poll}"
    transactionPerMessage="false">
        <jdbc:query key="read" value="${SQLServer.db.jdbc_query}" />
    </jdbc:connector>
```

from any of the flow ... Since it is declared as global ... it can be used from any of the flow in the application ..   what I mean is .. just remove the above line of code from one of the flow ... since you have declared in both the flow I guess it's a duplicate and not required to place in each and every flow ...  and yes just mention the reference **connector-ref="SQLServer-jdbcConnector"** in both the mule flow ... ex:-

```
<jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="read"
        connector-ref="SQLServer-jdbcConnector">
```

Comment: One more thing I noticed ... you have written <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://host:port/schema" /> where as in other flow you have mentioned database name Schema <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=schema" />... you missed the " databaseName=" in the first flow

Comment: The reason I have two data source references is because I need to use two different databases, and they are not duplicates.  Also, I didn't miss the "databaseName" in the first flow, that is just the difference between connection strings for MySQL and SQLServer.